# Saving .csv as .xlsx

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with converting files to another format. I have over few hundred files in .csv format and need to convert them. I found a sub() that is working but formatting looks different if I firstly open file and then save it manually. Where does it comes from?

Here is macro I use without opening files:

```
Sub csv_to_xlsx()
Dim CSVfolder As String, _
    XlsFolder As String, _
    fname As String, _
    wBook As Workbook

 CSVfolder = "C:\Users\ja\Desktop\CSV\"
 XlsFolder = "C:\Users\ja\Desktop\XLSX\"

 fname = Dir(CSVfolder & "*.csv")

 Do While fname <> ""
    Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
    wBook.SaveAs XlsFolder & Replace(fname, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wBook.Close False
    fname = Dir
 Loop
End Sub
```

And macro with opening files:

```
Sub open_csv_save_xlsx()

Dim sciezka As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sciezka = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
fileName = Dir(sciezka & "*.csv")
Do While fileName <> ""
i = i + 1
j = 2
Cells(i, 1) = fileName
fileName = Dir()
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, arkusz As String, XlsFolder As String, wBook As Workbook
XlsFolder = "C:\Users\ja\Desktop\XLSX\"
a = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
b = 1
For i = 1 To a - 1
arkusz = Range("A" & b).value
Range("C" & b).value = b
b = b + 1
Workbooks.Open (sciezka & arkusz)
Set wBook = ActiveWorkbook
wBook.SaveAs XlsFolder & Replace(sciezka & arkusz, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
Next i

End Sub
```

First part is making list of files in worksheet, and it crush at line `wBook.SaveAs XlsFolder & Replace(sciezka & arkusz, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook` and I do not know the reason. Error 1004 occurs.

Anyone have any other way to convert this files? And why difference in formatting occurs?

Comment: Both of those code blocks open the workbook and the first one isn't making a list of files. Try stepping through the code first to get an understanding of what it's actually doing.

Comment: @MacroMan Yes you are right, there is function .Open in first macro. What I am not understanding is difference between manual saving and using SUB(). Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're specifying a directory twice, both in `XlsFolder` and `scienka`.

Amending your code to this should reveal the issue:

```
MsgBox XlsFolder & Replace(sciezka & arkusz, ".csv", "")
wBook.SaveAs XlsFolder & Replace(sciezka & arkusz, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

I imagine you need to remove `scienka &`.

Comment: Yes! Perfect match. It solved problem with error 1004 but final effect still does not meet expectations. Problem is about I am not understanding  difference between manual saving and using SUB(). Do you have any idea about this? Maybe I should use some other file format then xlOpenXMLWorkbook? I would like workbooks after using macro will look like I saved it manually.

Comment: Have you tried adding the extension to it, i.e. `Replace(arkusz, ".csv", ".xlsx")`?

Comment: Didn't help. I got stuck with this problem.

Comment: When I do it manually file looks the same (identical values in cells) and only format changes (csv->xlsx). But when i use macro a lot of cells are merged and a o lot of semicolons are inserted.

Comment: Is it like this as soon as the file is opened in Excel (before saving)? Could you post a sample of the file?

Comment: Unfortunately i can not share a sample file. But you can check this on any file with values in few cells. There is a difference between manual/macro saving into .xlsx format.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this, could you post dummy CSV data (keep the same format, but scramble the characters)?